# EntityFramework 4.3 - Creating DbContext from Database without ObjectContext?

Tags: entity-framework-4, dbcontext, ef-database-first

Following the tutorial on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg715119 it describes adding an EDMX Entity Data Model to my solution (which generates cluttered models including `ObjectContext` from my db) and **after that** the tutorial generates a `DbContext` by clicking "Add item..." on the EDMX designer (because this is where the option Generate DbContext is available).

Is this the way to go if I want to work with EF 4.3 `DbContext`? Isn't it possible somehow to create a model from my database while only using `DbContext`?

I don't really want the `ObjectContext` with EDMX file in my solution. Just the `.tt` files. **Is this possible?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use DbContext (or any other template) you have to first turn off default code generation which produces ObjectContext - in EDMX property window remove custom tool for code generation.

Comment: Great, I thought I was missing something here!